# Array changes value

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

```
 boolean[][] grid = {{false,false},
                     {false,false}};
 WorldState test1 = new WorldState(grid,0,0);
 System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
```

Why does the boolean value of the grid changes after I use in in the WorldState. Shouldnt it stay false because I am not assigning anything to grid. I The system prints out the grid and it is [[true, false], [false, false]]. I dont understand where the true is coming from. please tell me why it is changing to true. Thank you. Worlds state code below:

```
 public class WorldState
 {
     boolean[][]grid2;
     public WorldState(boolean[][] grid, int row, int col)
     {
        this.grid2=grid;
        this.grid2[row][col] = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Arrays and objects are copied by reference and not by value. By assigning one array to another you're not copying the array, you're just telling Java they're the same reference. You need to copy it.

Comment: run your code in [Java Visualize](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/#) and the issue will be more appearant

Comment: also see `Arrays.copyOf(boolean[], int)` to copy the array http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this does is reference the same grid `this.grid2=grid;`.

Try this instead

```
 boolean[][]grid2;
 public WorldState(boolean[][] grid, int row, int col)
 {
    int gridRow = grid.length;
    int gridCol = grid[0].length;

    grid2 = new boolean[gridRow][gridCol];

    for (int i = 0; i < gridRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridCol; j++){
            grid2[i][j] = grid[i][j];
        }
    }
    grid2[row][col] = true;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you.. simple solution.. I could not see it.

Comment: Keep in mind though that if the indices don't match, you will have a problem. So you may need some conditional `if` statement to check that the indices are equal